# javascript advance number onclick or on reload

Tags: javascript, random, onload

I display a random DIV every time my webpage is reloaded using a simple function. This produces too many repeats because I only have seven divs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*7+1);  
            window.onload = function() {
               if (randomNumber == 1) {
                  document.getElementById("n1").style.display = "inline";
               }
               if (randomNumber == 2) {
                  document.getElementById("n2").style.display = "inline";
               }
      ...[ETC. through 7]
     }
            }
    </script>
```

I would like to solve this by replacing the "random number" with a predictable "progressing number".  Can I advance a variable with every reload or onclick and execute the function to display each DIV in sequence? 1,2,3... displaying all seven divs before repeating.

I worry I would need cookies to do this with each individual visitor.  Because the traffic is very low (likely one visitor at a time), perhaps I could use code from a page counter to achieve this.

I searched for any examples of this in action but found none.  I would be very appreciative of any and all suggestions.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: use `localStorage`: **http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp**... No cookies needed

Comment: Yes! That looks very promising!  I want to figure out how to integrate it with my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the random number you are generating, generates 3 everytime so no wonder you are getting all the repeats of third div.. change your random number generation code with this one:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7)) + 1;
```

This will generate a random number between 1 and 7 randomly. Then to display that particular div, instead of so many if or switch statements, you can simply do it in one line considering your div ids are n1, n2, n3 and so on..

```
document.getElementById("n"+randomNumber).style.display = "inline";
```

Put these two lines inside `window.onload` function so everytime window loads, a new random number gets generated and that div gets displayed.

This will work perfectly for many visitors as each visitor will get it's unique random number and that particular div will be displayed. No need to go into cookies or stuff like that.

See the Working snippet below, everytime you run it, a random div will be displayed:

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (7)) + 1;

document.getElementById("n"+randomNumber).style.display = "inline";
```

```html
<div id="n1" style="display:none">DIV1</div>
<div id="n2" style="display:none">DIV2</div>
<div id="n3" style="display:none">DIV3</div>
<div id="n4" style="display:none">DIV4</div>
<div id="n5" style="display:none">DIV5</div>
<div id="n6" style="display:none">DIV6</div>
<div id="n7" style="display:none">DIV7</div>
```

*EDIT:* After understanding your question better (hopefully) and doing some research, i came up with a solution where you can retain the value of current div between page reloads, make a new html file on your computer, copy paste the following code and keep refreshing the page to see each div being displayed incrementally..

```
<!DOCTYPE HMTL>
<html>
<body>
<div id="n1" style="display:none">DIV1</div>
<div id="n2" style="display:none">DIV2</div>
<div id="n3" style="display:none">DIV3</div>
<div id="n4" style="display:none">DIV4</div>
<div id="n5" style="display:none">DIV5</div>
<div id="n6" style="display:none">DIV6</div>
<div id="n7" style="display:none">DIV7</div>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    if(window.name === "" || parseInt(window.name, 10) === 8) //this condition will be true when the page loads for the first time or the div values (window.name) exceeds 7 (Number of divs)
        window.name = 1;
    document.getElementById("n"+window.name).style.display = "inline";
    window.name = parseInt(window.name,10) + 1;  //incrementing the div number..
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Sorry my question wasn't clear.  I used an ellipsis to communicate the code was truncated for space for this site once it started repeating.  I am currently generating seven divs by random.  I would like to display them in sequence so all seven are shown before it repeats.

Comment: That's very different from what i initially understood.. so you want to generate numbers 1-7 randomly and display all divs in that sequence?

Comment: It's my fault.  I wasn't clear.  I want to REPLACE my current random code with something that will show the DIVs in sequence before repeating.

Comment: you need a new div to be generated everytime the page loads.. from 1-7 in sequence and the repeat. right?

Comment: Yes.  I don't know if this is even possible.  I've seen sites display quotes, but they appear to use random functions.

Comment: You're welcome.. there were plenty of other ways of doing this but i thought this is the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: Although the question has an accepted answer, I thought this was a closer to the question solution, so I posted it after reading the lines in the OP `Can I advance a variable with every reload or onclick and execute the function to display each DIV in sequence? 1,2,3... displaying all seven divs before repeating.` which meant that the OP author did not want to show them randomly through the divs.

You could use `localStorage` to make this happen. This will rotate through the 7 divs sequentially and display one at each page load and it's going to be user specific. That means, every user is assured to see all the divs sequentially.

```
if (typeof(Storage) != 'undefined') { // Check if localStorage is available in the browser
    prevDiv = localStorage.getItem("myShowDiv"); // Fetch the previous that was shown to this browser

    if (!isNaN(prevDiv)) prevDiv = parseInt(prevDiv); // If not first time
    else prevDiv = parseInt('0'); // If it's first time

    nowDiv = prevDiv + 1; // This div will be shown
    if (nowDiv > 7) nowDiv = 1; // When all divs have been shown start from 1

    localStorage.setItem("myShowDiv",nowDiv); // Save this div id for next page load

    document.getElementById("div"+nowDiv).style.display = "inline"; // Show the div
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tafhim/3ozoxavu/50/)